# Raspbian Jessie, Autostart Python Script after GUI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to autostart a python script, pygame file once Rasbian boots up. I have tried changing the autostart file in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi` to:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi  
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi  
@python /home/pi/faller/main.py  
@xscreensaver -no-splash  
@point-rpi
```

from

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi  
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi  
@xscreensaver -no-splash  
@point-rpi
```

But nothing happens. Although when I have tried autostarting lxterminal in this way it works using

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi  
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi  
@lxterminal   
@xscreensaver -no-splash  
@point-rpi
```

I'm using 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie as this is the latest version that the TFT screen i'm using works with.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this technique.

Create a service:

```
$ sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/myautostartscript.service
```

Copy the following code and paste it (for Python 2.7; replace `python2.7` with `python3` for Python 3) and edit WorkingDirectory (`your_python_file.py` file directory) :

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2.7 -u your_python_file.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/myscript
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Give execution permission to your_python_file.py file:

```
$ sudo chmod +x your_python_file.py
```

Give auto Start Enable command:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable myautostartscript.service
```